# Intercept bot messages before send in bot framework v4 Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, botframework

I need to add fields before sending the object so I tried

```
    turnContext.onSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, nextSend) => {
        for (let activity of activities){
            activity.channelData.data='hi'
            console.log(activity)
                    }
        return await nextSend();
    })
```

but it doesn't reflect as what I understand the activities have been already sent and the function is for logging.

is there any way to make it work ?

Comment: Are you trying to alter an incoming activity from a user or an outgoing activity going somewhere else (i.e. storing the conversation in a database)? Also, which channel is this for?

Comment: @StevenKanberg I need to add an object with outgoing activity from the bot to the user

Answer (score 0):

Just include the `onSendActivities()` function within a handler. Then be sure to `return await next()` before proceeding to any following code, including the handler's `await next()`. The following setup will append the `{ data: 'hi' }` object to every activity.

The only other step is to decide the right handler and the right logic to send the data you want when you want.

Hope of help!

```js
this.onTurn(async (turnContext, next) => {

  await turnContext.onSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, next) => {
    for (let activity of activities) {
      activity.channelData = { data: 'hi' };
    }
    return await next();
  });

  await next();
});
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but in directline it doesn't reach the otherside

Comment: What channel are you running this on? I'm assuming it's for [web chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). Can you post your code for your index.js, "mainBot.js", and the relevant "mainDialog.js" files?